# dynamic allocation of multiple 2d char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need to define two string arrays as follows

```
char *Arry1[x];
char *Arry2[y];
```

x is constant defined as macro.

```
y = ( 2*(z+1))
```

where z is a variable.

While executing the program , i find that sizeof(Arry2) is 8. Why is it so?

Also, I'm executing the below loop

```
for ( i=0; i<40; i++)
{

     Arry1[i] = (char*) calloc ( 1, sizeof(Arry1) );
     Arry2[i] = (char*) calloc ( 1, sizeof(Arry2) );

     sprintf ( Arry1[i], "%s", VarX );
     sprintf ( Arry2[i], "%s", VarY );
}
```

VarX and VarY are two strings read from file

When I try to assign VarY to `Arry2[i]`, contents of `Arry1` are getting corrupted.

Comment: These are two separate and different questions. `sizeof(Arry2)` is 8 because Arry2 has likely been sized to 8 to keep memory-alignment. What do you mean by "contents Arry1 are getting corrupted"?

Comment: Is `z` equal to zero by any chance?

Comment: the value of z is not zero.

Comment: suppose Arry1[0] is "abcd", after assigning Arry2[3] , the value of Arry1[0] changes to "swef".

Comment: @PrathyushaSuggu Somehow I have hard time believing it. Please show the entire code with the declaration of `Arry2`, add the following code immediately after the declaration, and see what it prints: `printf("Size=%zu, z=%d\n", sizeof(Arry2), z);`

Comment: `char *Arry1[x]` means that you can store `x` `char *`-pointers, `sizeof(Arry1)` is `x * sizeof(char *)`. Why would you reserve an amount of memory for each of them directly related to the number of `char *`-pointers you can store in that array?